# Run dotnet console in background from test

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have console project (hosted with .net core 2.2) which hosts me grpc server.

We crated method

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
```

with all configuration

and then we created test project like this :

```
[Fact]
public async Task Sample_TestHost1()
{
    var builder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(Array.Empty<string>());
    var host = builder.Build();
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var tt = Task.Run(() => host.Run(), tokenSource.Token);
    tt.GetAwaiter().GetResult();


    tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
}
```

we want to host console app in background with grpc server available and then use it from test, but with this approach this line `tt.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` hangs the test and debugger does not go any further. 
So how to host this to be possible to use method in hosted service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.GetResult()` is a blocking operation and will wait until the task is complete.

Comment: @kosnkov maybe not to call `tt.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`?